# Stopping and starting loops in arduino

Tags: c, arduino, microcontroller

I need a motor to cycle forward, then backward when the user pushes a once. the problem is, the arduino will run in loops after it is presses and wont stop.

How can i make it only cycle through once each time the button is pushed?

Ive tried exit(0), stop_it, etc, but those just exit the loop instead of starting back up when the button is pressed another time.

```
const int pwm_pin = 9;
const int dir_1a_pin = 8;
const int dir_2a_pin = 7;
int buttonPin = 2;
boolean on=false;
int buttonState = 0;

void setup() {
pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
pinMode(pwm_pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(dir_1a_pin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(dir_2a_pin, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

if (buttonState == HIGH){
  if (on==true){
    on=false;
  } else{
    on=true;
  }
 }
if(on == true){ 
digitalWrite(dir_1a_pin, HIGH);
digitalWrite(dir_2a_pin, LOW);
analogWrite(pwm_pin, 255);
delay (8000);

digitalWrite(dir_1a_pin, LOW);
digitalWrite(dir_2a_pin, HIGH);
analogWrite(pwm_pin, 255);
delay (12000);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making the logic too much complicated. Just read the button state in your loop and if it was `HIGH` do your motorcycle job. The next time loop runs as you haven't pressed the button it would become `LOW` and won't go into if statement.

```
const int pwm_pin = 9;
const int dir_1a_pin = 8;
const int dir_2a_pin = 7;
int buttonPin = 2;

void MotorCycle()
{
    digitalWrite(dir_1a_pin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(dir_2a_pin, LOW);
    analogWrite(pwm_pin, 255);
    delay(8000);

    digitalWrite(dir_1a_pin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(dir_2a_pin, HIGH);
    analogWrite(pwm_pin, 255);
    delay(12000);
}

void setup()
{
    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(pwm_pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(dir_1a_pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(dir_2a_pin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    // if button pressed
    if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH)
    {
        MotorCycle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the part you want to run once is in the section at the end in the if(on == true) section.  If you don't want that to repeat, then how about setting on to false in that section.  Then next time loop repeats it won't go into that section.